# Horizontally center img and text in a div with padding in between

Tags: css

HTML

```
      <div id="container">
      <img src="1.jpg" />
      <span> text next to image</span>
      </div>
```

How would you center the image and span in the div container and ensure a padding of 5px between the img and the span using css

Comment: Can you please post the CSS you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the text to be next to the image? Like this?

```
  <div id="container" style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="image.png" />
  <span style="padding-left: 5px;"> text next to image</span>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8m26G/